# How to cast in Java from type Node to Integer in Binary Tree?

Tags: java, casting, integer, binary-tree

I've kinda specific problem. I need to implement usual binary tree methods, but after I'm done with that I have to add "hits". More concretely, every time I find some Node (or just traverse it) that Node gets a hit. Example given:

Imagine normal Binary Tree with two parents and two children. Let's assume I have to find one of the two children. In order for me to do that, I have to traverse the root, then the parents before I can get to a children. Therefore, every of these Nodes that were traversed will get a hit. And it accumulates over the time. So obviously, root will always have most hits. I hope I made it easier to understand.

I implemented methods and it works just fine. Unfortunately, every time new Node is created, number of hits should be set to 0. That's where the problem comes.
I declared `int[] hitCounter = new int[]` and with the following code:

```
public class BinaryTree {
    Node root;
    int[] hitCounter = new int[1000];

    public void add(int data) {

        Node addingNote = new Node(data);

        if (root == null) {
            root = addingNote;
            hitCounter[addingNode] = 0;
        } else
            addNode(root, addingNote);

    }
```

I assumed that this would work, but obviously `hitCounter[addingNode] = 0;` does not work since `hitCounter` is Array type and `addingNode` is Node type. How should I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Why isn't `hitCounter` an `int` variable in `Node` class? Besides, `hitCounter` isn't an integer type, it's an array type. You've got a lot of things wrong in your question. This has nothing to do with casting either. You should read a tutorial to work out the basics first.

Comment: How should it go then ? addingNote.hitCounter = 0; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be easier if each node had its own hit count. Then every time that node is accessed you could call a function that increments the hit count by 1 (hitCountIncrement). You could also have a method on each node that resets hit count to 0 (hitCountReset). Finally, you could have a method in your BinaryTree class that traverses all nodes and calls the hitCountReset method on each one when needed.

Edit:

Example code

```
public class Node{

int hitCount = 0; //this should be set in the constructor

public void hitCountIncrement() {
    hitCount++;
}

public void hitCountReset() {
    hitCount = 0;
}
}

public class BinaryTree {

    public void resetAllCounts(){
    for(Node currNode:Nodes){
        currNode.hitCountReset();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Makes more sense, indeed.